# How do you write a line of output?

Tags: basic

I was assigned a program for class, and I have to make a line of output say "Hello World". I don't know how o do this, please help

Comment: Have you not attended a single class yet? Isn't this something that's covered, you know, in the class materials?

Comment: If only solving [Hello World](http://www.roesler-ac.de/wolfram/hello.htm) was a classic and time honoured tradition in development. Someone could  actually list how to accomplish it in virtually every language. Such a pity

Answer (score 5):

```
10 PRINT "Hello World"
```

Should pretty much do it for a BASIC program.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many approaches to this question, for example:

```
10 V$ = "Hello world."
20 PRINT V$
```

is one.

Comment: I don't see that this adds anything helpful to the discussion.  This is merely a 2-line version of the prior answer.

Comment: It just indicates there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: You should've edited your old post and included your second approach to the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to the hello world could be:

```
10 READ V$
20 PRINT V$
30 DATA "Hello world."
```

and I could go on but these should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another:

```
10 REM hello world program
20 FOR L = 1 TO 12
30     READ a
40     PRINT CHR$(a);
50 NEXT
60 PRINT
70 DATA 72,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100,46
```

Comment: Note DATA statement includes ascii keyboard values.